# "A connection attempt failed because the connected party did not properly respond after a period of time"

Tags: mysql, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, mysql-workbench, mysql-connector

I have a project in Asp Net MVC 4.5.2 and a Mysql database it is connected to. For a few days, my project started getting errors from Mysql. Everything goes smoothly through the project, however, whenever I do something on the Mysql workbench (such as indexing or adding rows to any table and .s), my project immediately gets the following error from Mysql and everything gets an error until Mysql restarts. Mysqle is working again after restarting. I can't figure out what the problem is.

The first time I got the error was when you indexed the tables to speed up the search queries. I thought that the problem was with the indexes and I took it back, but after that day, whatever I do in Mysql, the project immediately gets an error.

Always the error:

```
A connection attempt failed because the connected party did not properly respond 
after a period of time, or established connection failed because connected host 
has failed to respond
```

Comment: Please post TEXT results of A) SHOW GLOBAL VARIABLES LIKE '%timeo%"; and B) SELECT @@version: for analysis.

Answer (score 0):

The indexing you performed might have caused high resource usage on the MySQL server, leading to connection issues. Monitor the server's performance during your operations in MySQL Workbench to see if there are any resource bottlenecks.

Check the MySQL server logs for any errors, warnings, or performance-related messages. The logs are usually located in the MySQL data directory and have filenames like error.log or slow-query.log. Analyzing the logs can provide valuable insights into any issues or resource bottlenecks the server might be experiencing.